# Minimizing header import

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I just thought up a simple scenario for myself to play around with `NSClassFromString` and the Objective-C runtime.

***Background:***

Imagine I had a class method in which I create an instance from a class based on some condition, let's say:

```
Class class;
id object;
if(classNumber == 1)
{
    //create ClassA
    class = NSClassFromString(@"classA");
    object = [[class alloc] init];
}
else if(classNumber == 2)
{
    //create ClassB
    class = NSClassFromString(@"classB");
    object = [[class alloc] init];
}
else if(classNumber == 3)
{
    //create ClassC
    class = NSClassFromString(@"classC");
    object = [[class alloc] init];
}
else
{
   object = nil;   
}
return object;
```

For the runtime version, I would replace the above and use within the above `if-elseif-else` respectively:

```
Class class = objc_allocateClassPair([classA class], "mySubClass", 0);
...
Class class = objc_allocateClassPair([classB class], "mySubClass", 0);
...
Class class = objc_allocateClassPair([classC class], "mySubClass", 0);
...
```

Both versions go well. But I have to `#import` nonetheless all these `classX`.

And given this is a class method and will be called only once, I wonder if there exist some clever way of creating a class without having to import all these headers.

I understand that the answer will most likely be "No", because the compiler needs to know the class and its method signature at compile time.

But my experience is that whenever I say *"Ok, I think I am pushing a bit here. Let's settle what seems to work now"*, someone would come along and would refute my satisfaction by saying *"Hey, look here, there is a better/more clever way to do this. It's possible."*. So I thought I would ask.

***To sum up the question:*** is it possible to minimize `#import`ing as much as possible, if we only needed to create a class from one of the files that need to be imported? Or is there some clever way where we could dynamically import a header file?

Answer (score 1):

First off, I really don't see the point of this. For one thing, you still need to link the object files for all those classes into the final binary. So you can't minimize the binary size by using reflection and manipulating your includes.

So you can only try to optimize the number of include statements. Is it really worth it, just to remove a couple of lines of code? Of course, you could include the required headers into a new header file, and just include that one. That would cut down the number of includes to 1. Is it worth the trouble? I don't know.